# Rewriting URLs from subdomain to domain in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

My webserver is running Plesk and part of my site structure goes like this:

```
/
/httpdocs (domain root folder, URL: http://www.domain.com)
/subdomains
/subdomains/blog/httpdocs (blog root folder, URL: http://blog.domain.com)
```

I have a WordPress installation in the domain root folder and WP is configured to display a static page when accessing `www.domain.com` and to display the blog when accessing `www.domain.com/blog`.

However, I want to redirect (using mod_rewrite) all requests from http://blog.domain.com/ to http://www.domain.com/blog/.

A few examples:

Accessing http://blog.domain.com/archives should access http://www.domain.com/blog/archives/
Accessing http://blog.domain.com/tag/abc should access http://www.domain.com/blog/tag/abc/
Accessing http://blog.domain.com/some-post-title should access http://www.domain.com/blog/some-post-title

All this should be transparent to the user, the address shouldn't be changed on the browser's address bar. In better words, I want a URL rewrite and not a URL redirect.

Is this achievable with mod_rewrite? Can anyone help me with the .htaccess? All my attempts on doing so have failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course proxy the requests from `blog.example.com` to `example.com/blog`. You can find [simple examples for a reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#examples) in the documentation for mod_proxy. Just place the directives in an `.htaccess` file in the document root of `blog.example.com` or put them into the respective `vhost.conf` file.

But I really don't see any advantage over just redirecting the clients which you can achieve by simply placing an `.htaccess` file into the document root of `blog.example.com` with the content:

```
RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.com/blog/
```

Comment: Because, like I said, I don't want a URL redirect, I want a URL rewrite.